# Change a movie name with PUT method using forEach and IF

Tags: node.js, express

Im looking for some help to resolve an exercise.. Im learning about the PUT method and how can i change a movie object... I need to use a forEach, an IF, and a req.body.

The initial code is:

```
let movies = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Spider-Man',
    duration: 129,
    genre: 'Adventure'
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'Toy Story 4',
    duration: 100,
    genre: 'Animation'
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'X-Men',
    duration: 113,
    genre: 'Action'
}
```

];

const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

Im adding a

router.put('/movies/:id', function(req, res){ }

but i don't know what to put inside the {}

Comment: What do you use for database management? You don't use MVC? refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/model-view-controllermvc-architecture-for-node-applications/#:~:text=MVC%20is%20an%20acronym%20for,divided%20into%20three%20interconnected%20parts.). Anyway, you need to build a controller for it.

Comment: Call the controller without curly brackets. Just like `router.put('/movies/:id', Controller.UpdateMoviceName)`.

Answer (score 1):

> i don't know what to put inside the {}

Code that contains logic to update the array.

For example:

```
router.put('/movies/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    // get id from :id, parse it to an int
    let id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10) || false

    // validate
    if (!id) {
      let err = new Error('Invalid movie id')
      err.status = 422
      throw err
    }

    // find the movie
    let index = movies.findIndex(v => v.id === id)

    if (index === -1) {
      let err = new Error('Movie not found')
      err.status = 404
      throw err
    }

    // seems good, now lets validate body
    let errors = {}

    // id
    if (!req.body.id) {
      errors.id = 'Id is a required field'
    } else if (isNaN(req.body.id)) {
      errors.id = 'Id is invalid, number required'
    }

    //title
    if (!req.body.title) {
      errors.title = 'Title is a required field'
    } else if (req.body.title.length <= 1) {
      errors.title = 'Title too short, enter greater than 1 character'
    } else if (req.body.title.length >= 255) {
      errors.title = 'Title too long, enter less than 255 characters'
    }

    // duration
    if (typeof req.body.duration === 'undefined') {
      errors.duration = 'Duration is a required field'
    } else if (req.body.duration < 0) {
      errors.duration = 'Duration cannot be negative, enter greater than 0 minute'
    } else if (req.body.duration >= 1440) {
      errors.duration = 'Duration too long, enter less than than 1440 minutes (1 day)'
    }

    //genre
    if (!req.body.genre) {
      errors.genre = 'Genre is a required field'
    }

    // has errors
    if (Object.keys(errors).length) {
      let err = new Error('Invlid inputs')
      err.status = 422
      err.errors = errors
      throw err
    }

    //
    movies[index] = {
      id: req.body.id,
      title: req.body.title,
      duration: req.body.duration,
      genre: req.body.genre
    }

    // send success response
    res.json({
      status: 200
    })
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

Error handler to catch what was thrown from middleware

```
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {

  // set response header
  res.status(error.status || 500)

  // is xhr/ajax
  if (req.xhr) {
    res.json(error)
  }
  // not ajax
  else {
    res.render('error', error)
  }
})
```