# how to write/throw errors in javascript web development?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand, we can use try and catch block for catching any runtime errors, see code sample below.
I am new to async/await coding paradigm, but I'm assuming, there is no issue with how i catch errors below. I am assuming , if I wanted to throw an error if user is null , in the code below, how do i do that? is that a custom error or can i just do -
if I wanted to catch and rethrow this to some common piece of error handling function/code in my app , how do i do that?

pseudocode

```
if (user == undefined or null)
   throw Error()
```

```
var express = require("express");
const models = require("../models");

router.get("/user/", async (req, res) => {
  try { 
 
    const user = await user.getUser();   
 
    res.status(200).send({ ...user.toJSON() });

  } catch (err) {

       res.status(400).send({ status: false, error: 'something went wrong' ) })
  }
});
```

Comment: utilise next in your middleware `async (req, res, next) => {` then in the catch use it and let the global error handler pick it up

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - thanks, I am new to javascript/node web development . I am assuming next is another library , i can download. is there a example or any links , you can point me to?

Comment: no, rtm [error-handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html), see this old answer, shows example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847371/change-a-movie-name-with-put-method-using-foreach-and-if/66847669#66847669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think the controller is the best place to throw an exception. You can just respond directly with the http error code.
Usually, you throw in the services layer or under ( for exemple in the getUser function ) to break the logic and you assume it will be catched in the controller. In the controller, you can respond with different error code according the error type.
You can do that behavior globaly in your app by making a middleware to map your Errors to the right http Error code.

For example: In getUser, if user === null, throw NotFoundError (custom error extending Error). In the middleware or the controller, if error is instance of NotFoundError, res by a 404.

Comment: thanks. I agree , I'm new to webdevelopment in javascript , so starting with the simple example. do you have a example of how to write a custom function/class ( I know , we can do that in javascript now) or how to extend error class ( examples , links would be great)

Comment: You can find some examples there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. if you know of any projects/blogs samples , which can help me understand do's and don'ts , for example - not throwing "not found user" in controller, like you mentioned. please point me to those

Comment: I found an example of pre condition https://github.com/lujakob/nestjs-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/profile/profile.service.ts#L52

Comment: As you can see, in the service, if there is missing parameter, it throw an exception.
And in the contoller : https://github.com/lujakob/nestjs-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/profile/profile.controller.ts
The catching is transparent because there is a middleware that handle it. A framework one probably

Comment: And, this is a example of exception middleware for express: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score -1):

With express, you can use two optional parameters called `next` and `err`, which if you know about express middleware functions, you know that to move to the next function in the middleware pipeline, you use `next()`. Little do some know that you can use `next` and `err` together to pass an error.

So, using the snippet you gave, you can do the following.

```
const express = require("express");
const models = require("../models");

router.get("/user/", async (err, req, res, next) => {
  try { 
    const user = await user.getUser();   

    if (!user) {
      // use of next and err, will throw error and not exucute
      // the rest of the function.
      return next(err)
    }

    res.status(200).send({ ...user.toJSON() });
  } catch (err) {
     res.status(400).send({ status: false, error: 'something went wrong' ) })
  }
});
```

Personally, I don't like using the implementation shown above, because it is much simpler to let the response in the catch block do the work, but if you really need to handle and error, you can use this method.

Comment: thanks, I just restarted reading the documentation. Thanks, i did not know , that next is used to move the execution to the next function in the middleware. I was under impression that it is strictly used for error handling. so thanks. so the "return next(err) will move the execution to the catch block ?